# Protractor: ERROR loading configuration file

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

After installing protractor and starting selenium webdriver, I have a problem about run config.js file on example folder on protractor: ERROR loading configuration file config.js, as in the below picture:
[image: command window screen shot]

The config.js file is a default file on example folder. I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Protractor 3.2.2, within the Protractor folder there is a folder called example which contains conf.js. You need to cd to the example folder and then run the command `protractor conf.js`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is your command cannot find file config.js. Need to run command exactly folder.

Answer (score -1):

It is throwing up the following error in the dialog box

> Failed to load extension from : C:\Users....\Appdata\local\Temp\scoped_dir7816_9439\internal.Lodaing of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator